# Is there a site on Stack Exchange where it is allowed to ask for website reviews?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

So I've been working on my own website for a while now, and now it's in a decent condition so I thought I'd ask for some reviews, opinions of other users, to know what I could add yet to improve the site, what I should fix etc.

But I don't know if there's such site on SE where it is allowed.

If that counts, my website is about anime, and I saw there is a [Stack Exchange site](https://anime.stackexchange.com/)
about anime, so I thought maybe there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, not really. The main problems with those kind of questions are:

- Too broad - depending on the size of the website, there can be too many things to improve. If you can focus on one specific thing on your website, the question might work better.
- Opinion based - what one person finds awesome, another one might find awful and vice versa. Stack Exchange works better with *objective* answers.
- Not self-contained; we generally require all the information necessary to answer a question *in the question itself*. Your site is per definition in another location.
- At Stack Exchange, we're trying to build a library of general purpose questions and answers. Site reviews are about the opposite of this; they are only useful for a single person. That's why a few sites have explicitly made them off-topic, for example:

> Questions that are **specific to one website** are discouraged because they are unlikely to help future visitors. Examples include individual website reviews for SEO purposes and general website troubleshooting. See the How to Ask page for help improving this question.

([Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com))

> Questions about **Site Reviews** are off-topic because questions here are expected to be relevant for a variety of people in the same situation. Reviewing a site, flow or interface only helps one person at a specific time. Instead try to ask a focused question about a particular aspect of the design that solicits solutions, not opinions.

([User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com))

Your best bet within the Stack Exchange network is probably to become an active part of the community about the topic of your site, and once you gain a bit of a name / reputation, ask in the main chatroom if somebody is interested in reviewing your website. Don't get too pushy if nobody reacts, though.